# Reading Data From Database and storing in Array List object

Tags: java, jdbc

Hello all i want to display entire content  of my database table on html page.I am trying    to fetch record from database first and store in `ArrayList` but when i return array list on html page it display only last record repeatedly as count of my database table.
Here is the code below :

```
public ArrayList<CustomerDTO> getAllCustomers() 
{
    ArrayList<CustomerDTO> customers = new ArrayList<CustomerDTO>();
    CustomerDTO customer = null;
    Connection c;
    try {
        c = openConnection();
        Statement statement = c.createStatement();
        String s = "SELECT * FROM customer";

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(s);
        int g =0;

        while (rs.next()) {

            customer.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            customer.setName(rs.getString("name"));

            customer.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            customer.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
            customer.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            customer.setBountPoints(rs.getInt("bonuspoint"));
            customer.setTotalsale(rs.getInt("totalsale"));

            customers.add(customer);
        }

        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return customers;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try with the following code

```
public static ArrayList<Customer> getAllCustomer() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn=DBConnection.getDBConnection().getConnection();
    Statement stm;
    stm = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "Select * From Customer";
    ResultSet rst;
    rst = stm.executeQuery(sql);
    ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rst.next()) {
        Customer customer = new Customer(rst.getString("id"), rst.getString("name"), rst.getString("address"), rst.getDouble("salary"));
        customerList.add(customer);
    }
    return customerList;
}
```

this is my  model class

```
public class Customer {
private String id;
private String name;
private String salary;
private String address;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(String salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

this is my view method

```
  private void reloadButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try {
        ArrayList<Customer> customerList = null;
        try {
            try {
                customerList = CustomerController.getAllCustomer();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(veiwCustomerFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ViewCustomerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) customerTable.getModel();
        tableModel.setRowCount(0);
        for (Customer customer : customerList) {
            Object rowData[] = {customer.getId(), customer.getName(), customer.getAddress(), customer.getSalary()};
            tableModel.addRow(rowData);
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ViewCustomerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a new customer object in every iteration and then add that newly created object into the ArrayList at the lase of your iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the `customer` reference. Java works by reference for Obejcts. Not for primitives.

What you are doing is adding to the list the same `customer` and then modifying it. Thus setting the same values for all of objects. That's why you see the last. Because all are the same.

```
 while (rs.next()) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(rs.getInt("id"));

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating new instance of customer every time e.g.

```
         while (rs.next()) {

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        customer.setName(rs.getString("name"));

        customer.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
        customer.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
        customer.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        customer.setBountPoints(rs.getInt("bonuspoint"));
        customer.setTotalsale(rs.getInt("totalsale"));

        customers.add(customer);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.rcb.dbconnection.DbConnection;
import com.rcb.model.Docter;


public class DocterService {



public ArrayList<Docter> getAllDocters() {
    ArrayList<Docter> docters = new ArrayList<Docter>();

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT tbl_docters";

        ResultSet rs = db.getData(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Docter docter = new Docter();

            docter.setD_id(rs.getInt("d_id"));
            docter.setD_FName(rs.getString("d_fname"));
            docter.setD_LName(rs.getString("d_lname"));

            docters.add(docter);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("getAllDocters()");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return (docters);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    DocterService ds = new DocterService();
    ArrayList<Docter> doctersList = ds.getAllDocters();
    String s[] = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < doctersList.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(doctersList.get(i).getD_id());
        System.out.println(doctersList.get(i).getD_FName());
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I am trying to fetch record from database first and store in ArrayList
>   but when i return array list on html page it display only last record
>   repeatedly as count of my database table*

This part has mostly been covered by all the previous answers. So you would need to create a new instance of your `CustomerDTO` within your `while` loop and add it to your `ArrayList`.

There's  one more thing that I wanted to comment about:

- Make sure that you release all your resources after you're done using them. From the code that you've posted, you've not closed your `Statement` or your `Connection` objects (*not so sure if you're pooling your connection, in that case you would need to release this connection to the pool*)

So, when you consider these points, the structure of your code might look something like this:

```
public ArrayList<CustomerDTO> getAllCustomers() 
{
    ArrayList<CustomerDTO> customers = new ArrayList<CustomerDTO>();
    Connection c = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs        = null;

    try {
        c           = openConnection();
        statement   = c.createStatement();
        String s    = "SELECT * FROM customer";

        rs          = statement.executeQuery(s);
        int g =0;

        while (rs.next()) {
            CustomerDTO customer = new CustomerDTO();
            //Code to fill up your DTO
            customers.add(customer);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }finally{
        //Code to release your resources
    }

    return customers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your customer class has static variables remove them so your class should look something like this.

```
public class customer {

     private int id;
     private String name;
     private String DOB;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }
     public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setDOB(String dOB) {
        this.DOB = dOB;
    }
```

instead of something like

```
public class customer {

     private static int id;
     private static String name;
     private static String DOB;

    public static int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public static String getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }
     public static void setId(int id) {
        custumer.id = id;
    }
    public  static void setName(String name) {
        customer.name = name;
    }
    public static void setDOB(String dOB) {
        customer.DOB = dOB;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Instead of`null`, 
use CustomerDTO customers =`new CustomerDTO()`;

```
CustomerDTO customer = null;


  private static List<Author> getAllAuthors() {
    initConnection();
    List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
    Author author = new Author();
    try {
        stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        String str = "SELECT * FROM author";
        rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(str);

        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("nAuthorId");
            String name = rs.getString("cAuthorName");
            author.setnAuthorId(id);
            author.setcAuthorName(name);
            authors.add(author);
            System.out.println(author.getnAuthorId() + " - " + author.getcAuthorName());
        }
        rs.close();
        closeConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return authors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (rs.next()) {

            customer.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            customer.setName(rs.getString("name"));

            customer.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            customer.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
            customer.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            customer.setBountPoints(rs.getInt("bonuspoint"));
            customer.setTotalsale(rs.getInt("totalsale"));

            customers.add(customer);
             customer = null;
        }
```

Try replacing your while loop code with above mentioned code. Here what we have done is after doing `customers.add(customer)` we are doing customer = null;`

Answer (score 0):

> Create CustomerDTO Object every time inside while loop
>
> Check the below code

```
    while (rs.next()) {

    Customer customer = new Customer();

    customer.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    customer.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    customer.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
    customer.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
    customer.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
    customer.setBountPoints(rs.getInt("bonuspoint"));
    customer.setTotalsale(rs.getInt("totalsale"));

    customers.add(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also If you want you result set data in list .please use below LOC:

```
public List<String> dbselect(String query)
  {
      List<String> dbdata=new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
        dbResult=statement.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData metadata=dbResult.getMetaData();
        for(int i=0;i>=metadata.getColumnCount();i++)
        {
            dbdata.add(dbResult.getString(i));
        }
        return dbdata;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return null;
    }
      
      
  }
```